# Including service worker file "firebase-messaging-sw.js"

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a very real strange issue. When I deploy my project to a firebase hosting i've not problem. But when I deploy de SAME EXACT code in my public server i got the famous error code:

If I try to open the file in the firebase hosting, it opens succesfully:
https://XXXXX.firebaseapp.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js

But when I try to open in my public server, automatically redirects to the login page and it seems the file doesnt exist.

[image]

In my angular.json i have this:

[image]

The file existis in my src folder:

[image]

And when i run ng build --prod the file appears in the dist folder:

[image]

I dont know what to do !.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks (sorry my english, i speak spanish)